# Can I write two cron( hook_cron() ) in one module

Tags: cron

I have a custom module abc_xyz and i want to write two seperate cron for this module.

below is the code which i am trying but it is creating only one cron ,
with name abc_xyz_cron. it is not creating for zzz_yyy_cron

file name : abc_xyz.module

```
abc_xyz_cron(){

}

zzz_yyy_cron(){

}
```

Comment: can any one  help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can implement hooks once per module due to the namespacing of the hook (mymodule_cron). However you can put conditions within the cron hook to do different things.

You might be looking for this instead: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron_queue_info/7.x

Comment: I have confused with this document http://cgit.drupalcode.org/elysia_cron/tree/API.txt